# Handling concurrency while dealing with Database snapshots

Tags: c#, unit-testing, concurrency, sql-server-2012, snapshot

I am writing unit tests in .NET that are heavily dependent on database. Unit test modify the data in the database and I want to revert the database to the initial state. I am planning to follow the approach listed below for reverting the database to pre unit-test state.

Approach: I want to create a database snapshot before running each unit test and rollback database to that snapshot after it is finished.

**The problem**: many users can simultaneously run the test cases. This can result in different snapshots (inconsistent). How can I handle the concurrency problem? I do not want to pollute the database in any way for the sake of running test cases.

I am using SQL Server 2012 and .NET (C#) for accessing the database.

Comment: If your "unit tests" rely on the database, they aren't unit tests.

Comment: Even if we read "automated test" instead of "unit test", your approach is fundamentally flawed because you can't give each individual user their own copy of the database. A snapshot would merely allow reverting for one user. A more involved approach that nevertheless has a much better chance of succeeding is to have each user use their own local database server for these tests (for example, through LocalDB). You can import your production DB as a database project and have it deployed locally on each test run (or even each individual test, though that's much slower).

Comment: @JeroenMostert They are infact automation tests. I cannot use different database for each user. The tests use ca service call that modifies data in a central database :(

Comment: ...so run the service locally too? If you absolutely *must* use a shared instance, any concurrency issues can be solved by using mutual exclusion: have the tests create some sort of `lock` file in a shared location on start and remove it on end, and, if this file is present, they'll keep waiting until it's gone. Then wait for people to complain that someone aborted tests, left a `lock` file and now someone has to fix the mess... You really want to invest time and effort into decoupling your tests from any central authority. Yes, it's work, but the returns are worth it.